# Why isn't AJAX working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Anything I'm missing with the code below? I'm a bit overwhelmed.

```
$("a[id^='submitspam']").click(function () { 
    var thisForm = $(this).attr('id');
    var com_id = $(this).attr('id').substring(11);
    var thisFormFull = '#' + thisForm;

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
        url: "/songs/spam.php",
        data: "command=mark_spam&cid=" + com_id,

        complete: function(data){
            messageList = 'contentspam-' + com_id;
            $('span#' + messageList).html(data.responseText);
            $(thisFormFull).hide();
            $('span#' + messageList).fadeIn();
        }
    });

    return false;  
});
```

Comment: you checked if the click function is fired? This works on other browsers?

Comment: What isn't working? What have you tried? There's a lot you can do to improve your question.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me, but you could add an error handler to see if that gives you more details. How exactly is this not working for you?

Comment: Check to see if the selector is returning anything.

Comment: Sorry, the AJAX section isn't doing anything.  I can throw in alerts and the like before the ajax code and it'll work fine.  Nothing is hitting spam.php from Internet Explorer 7/8

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A site, not a debugger.

Comment: @Mike the spam.php returns something? Have you tried in other browsers to ensure that the problem is IE?

Comment: Yup.  I tried in just about all major browswers for OSX and Windows.  Nothing happens with IE7/8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me.  I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/Ghy5C/) with your code, and clicking the link in IE 8 generates a request.  I used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to inspect the HTTP request:

```
POST /songs/spam.php HTTP/1.1
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.3
Referer: http://fiddle.jshell.net/josh3736/Ghy5C/show/
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Zune 4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3)
Host: fiddle.jshell.net
Content-Length: 23
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

command=mark_spam&cid=1
```

Even though the AJAX request 404s (there's no spam.php on jsfiddle's server), the link is hidden after the request completes.  As an aside, you should make your callback function the [`success`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) callback rather than the `complete` callback, so that your UI does not report that an operation succeeded when in fact there was an error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Interesting it works in jsfiddle.  I suppose there could be something larger at play at my site then.